# Is there an $end$ version in vb.net for snippets?

Tags: vb.net, code-snippets

I'm making some snippets and i want to position the cursor. I've come acros "$end$" but all examples i see are in c#. Since recently i've started programming in vb.net again and it seems $end$ isn't recognized or doesn't work here. Is there another keyword in vb to do the same?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, no. MSDN doesn't do the best job of documenting the meta-languages of snippets so reverse engineering tends to be the best way to figure things out. Looking through all of the VB snippets I can't find any usage of `$selected$` or `$end$`. When I insert Microsoft-created snippets in VB I also can't press enter to go to the inside of my snippets like I can in C#.

Answer (score 0):

If you install SharpDevelop, it has a translator that will convert C# code to VB.NET.

Just open a .cs file and then Tools->Convert to->VB.NET

Comment: I've tried several converting tools and none of them recognizes the $end$ syntax for vb